# JavaScript problem with asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, async-await

I know there are already tons of questions on this topic, but I can't make my (asynchronous) code work and I could really use some help.

I have three functions with an AJAX call in each one. Each of these three functions eventually returns an array. When the three arrays are finally complete, I want to call another function `showInfo()` which has the three previoulsy received arrays as parameters.

What is my mistake?

```
showInfo(await getMovies(), await getActors(), await getGenres());

async function getMovies() {
    //Ajax request which eventually returns a 'movie' array
}

async function getActors() {
    //Ajax request which eventually returns an 'actor' array
}

async function getGenres() {
    //Ajax request which eventually returns a 'genre' array
}

function showInfo(movies, actors, genres){
    //process data
}
```

UPDATE:

I found my mistake. The `getMovies()`, `getActors()` and `getGenres()` functions did not include a promise. Also, these three functions do not need the `async`. The function which includes the `showInfo()` call (with the `await` statements)  however does.

Comment: What makes you think you made a mistake? Are any errors shown? You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: What you've shown *seems* OK assuming the comments are correct. We don't know if this is the case. Also, we don't know what problem you're getting.

Comment: I found my mistake. The `getMovies()`, `getActors()` and `getGenres()` functions did not include a promise. Also, these three functions do not need the `async`. The function which includes the `showInfo()` call (with the `await` statements)  however does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. The `getMovies()`, `getActors()` and `getGenres()` functions did not include a promise. Also, these three functions do not need the `async`. The function which includes the `showInfo()` call (with the `await` statements)  however does.

Now it is like this:

```
    doEverything();

    async function doEverything() {
        var movies = await getMovies();
        var actors = await getActors();
        var genres = await getGenres();
        showInfo(movies, actors, genres);
    }

    function getMovies() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            //Ajax request which eventually returns a 'movies' array
        });
    }

    function getActors() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            //Ajax request which eventually returns an 'actor' array
        });
    }

    function getGenres() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            //Ajax request which eventually returns a 'genres' array
        });
    }

    function showInfo(movies, actors, genres) {
        //process data
    }
```